# FlashBuilder output to SFTP

Tags: eclipse, debugging, sftp, flash-builder

I need to debug a Flex project on a remote server. The project has Linux backend.

I have access to the backend via WinSCP.

Is it possible to set up Adobe FlashBuilder to build to the server (what should I write in the Flex Build Path/Output folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish the same thing is to add WinSCP as a builder in your project's build steps. The downside is that this it means your project will only build on Windows.

How to do it:

1. Go to the "Builders" section under the project properties, and click on "New"
2. Choose a "Program" builder and click OK
3. Give the builder a descriptive name in the Name box (e.g. upload to your_server_name)
4. In the Location: part, put in the path to your WinSCP.exe
5. In the arguments box, put in command line options for the host you want to connect to and what you want WinSCP to do ( see [WinSCP command line options](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) ). For instance, I use:

   > ```
   > <user>@<host to upload to>:<ssh port> /synchronize ${workspace_loc:</<my project>/bin-debug>} <remote path>
   > ```
6. Okay all the dialogs.

Now, whenever you build, WinSCP will run after the build to upload your files to the server. You can use the checkboxes in the WinSCP dialogs to remove the prompts that you don't want.

Up until recently, I've been using the RSE part of the [Eclipse Target Management plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) for SFTP/SCP uploads from within Flex Builder. That would be a better solution for me because it's multi-platform; however I can't find a way to get rid of the last manual step, right-clicking on an RSE export preset file and telling it to export. Also, since RSE's SFTP upload support is flaky, with ridiculously long timeouts and poor quality error messages, it's not really suitable for use in my test running environment where the server details change often.